# Database Network Operations in Android

Tags: android, mysql

Hi I have developed a simple app in android that helps students prepare for the interviews.

Link : http://www.goo.gl/TgO1xq

Currently, all the data is stored in strings.xml and is static in nature. I am now planning to use remote mySQL database that can change the content dynamically on the go.

I was going through the below link on developer.google.com for understanding the storage options.

Link : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

This is the option I want to use for my next app
- Network Connection : Store data on the web with your own network server.

But I am not sure how to do it and the explanation is also very limited without any examples.

Please help me with the example code or some good sites which has examples related to the implementation of this techniques.

Any help is appreciated. Have a nice day...!!

Comment: Read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [On-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [Off-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a web service and database on the server.
Your database will have all the data and tables and the web service can avail the data in the suitable formats like JSON/XML. You can parse these data and can save it to the local SQLite database.
You can have a look on the following if you want to use the php for the service and MySQL for the database.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/